# Oracle: Fetching date data type values from cursor in pl/sql after storing values into cursor from table

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am not able to fetch date data type values from cursor after storing values into cursor from table. This is my pl/sql code

```
declare
   pname varchar(20);
        dename varchar(20);
        dname varchar(20);
    addate patient.addate%type;
cursor cur is select p.pname,p.pdisease,p.addate,d.dname from patient p,doctor d where p.pno=d.pno;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('details');
open cur;
loop
fetch cur into pname,dename,addate,dname;
exit when cur%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(pname||' '||pdisease||' 'addate||' 'dname);
end loop;
end;
/

Here in this code I am getting error like
ERROR at line 13:
ORA-06550: line 13, column 47:

    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ADDATE" when expecting one of the following:
    ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
    like4 likec as between from using || member submultiset
```

The select statement which i used to store values into the cursor is working fine I already checked it. But the problem is with fetching.

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> dbms_output.put_line(pname||' '||pdisease||' 'addate||' 'dname);

You are missing the **concatenation operator** for `addate` and `dname`. Correct it and it should work:

```
dbms_output.put_line(pname||' '||pdisease||' '||addate||' '||dname);
```